# Univariate distribution of observations using Seaborn having the same range of Xs

Tags: python, seaborn, probability-density

**Data** is a a univariate distribution of observations.

```
data = sns.distplot(frame,hist=False).get_lines()[0].get_data()
```

The range of Xs of the frame variable is (0,24), but the range of Xs of the data variable is (0,ca. 115?)

How do I create a distplot that has the same range of Xs as the frame? I a univariate distribution of observations with the same X range as the original function.

When I do the following (below), the maxima of the distributions are the maxima of the (0,ca. 115) function, not the original one.

```
x = data[0]
y = data[1]
plt.plot(y)
xt_y = argrelextrema(y,np.greater)
print(ext_y)
```

[image: Above- distplot, below - plot(data[1])(returned by get_lines()[0].get_data())]

Comment: Can you please add an image of the plot `sns.distplot(frame,hist=False, rug=True)` to your question? Without having the data nor the plot it's very hard to tell what's going on here.

Comment: It should be `plt.plot(x, y)`. You are plotting `range(len(y))` against `y`.

Comment: @cel Works, thank you. And how can I have X and Y written as a one dimensional array from 0 to 23?

Comment: @cel Also, can I use sns.distplot just for the data-- without plotting the distribution?

Comment: You are not using the right tool here. If you only want to fit the density distribution, you may want to google `Kernel Density Estimation python`.